Approximating the double integral of cosh(P) over [0,1]×[0,1] as mean(cosh(P))
On this website:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html
Towards the bottom of the URL, under the heading of "Large Problem", a python code
is given to numerically solve for P(x,y) for the equation of:
   ∇2 P = 10 ( ∫∫R  cosh(P) dx dy )2
where R=[0,1]x[0,1],  P(x,1) = 1, and P=0 elsewhere on the boundary of the square.
To set up the computer program, an assumption was made such that
   ( ∫∫R cosh(P) dx dy )  is approximated by ( mean(cosh(P)) )
I don’t understand how that assumption was derived.
I found this:
Expressing the double integral of cosh(xy) over [0,1]×[0,1] as a convergent sequence
But I don’t see that solution helping me.
Could someone please explain to me, in very simple language, how the assumption was derived?
Thanks in advance.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Is "mean" a sample mean? If so, see here.

I believe that "mean" is the sample mean.  From the python numpy module definition of the mean:
"Compute the arithmetic mean along the specified axis.  Returns the average
of the array elements."

@J.G Thanks for the assist.  The link you provided was very helpful and has answered my question.
